# inconsistent processing of YAML lists in R Markdown documents (related to loading of LaTeX packages)

Tags: yaml, latex, r-markdown

I would like to use R Markdown to produce a document that takes advantage of certain LaTeX packages. Sometimes, I want to render the Rmd document to PDF. At other times, I want to render it to HTML.

I would like to load packages via the `extra_dependencies` option, rather than through the `includes` or `header-includes` options. Some of the LaTeX packages should be loaded with options. Others shouldn't be.

When I render the Rmd document to PDF, there is no problem. But when I try to render the same document to HTML, `rmarkdown::render` chokes on the processing of the `extra_dependencies` argument. (I am using rmarkdown 2.1.) Here is a minimal example, following the style of the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-extra.html):

```
---
title: "Test Processing of YAML Header in R Markdown Document"
output: 
  html_document:
    extra_dependencies:
      array: null
      numprint: ["autolanguage"]
---

Hello.
```

Rendering that document with `rmarkdown::render` generates a `dependency_resolver -> <Anonymous> -> sapply -> lapply` error. If I add dashes before `array` and `numprint`, the error is instead `Error: invalid version specification 'NULL'`. But if I just change `html_document` to `pdf_document`, there is no problem.

How may I generate an HTML document while loading packages through the `extra_dependencies` option? And why does this example work when I generate PDF documents, but not when I generate HTML documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, the `extra_dependencies` argument is available for multiple different output formats (PDF, HTML), but these settings are output format specific.

If you want to assign **LaTeX packages**, these will will only work as an extra_dependency for **PDF outputs**. This is causing the error as it doesn't recognise the syntax of the extra dependency. To get your code to work you need to provide separate options for HTML and PDF:

```
---
title: "Test Processing of YAML Header in R Markdown Document"
output: 
  html_document: default
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies:
      array: null
      numprint: ["autolanguage"]
---

Hello.
```

You could specify extra dependencies for an **HTML document**, but these will have to be **HTML dependencies**, not LaTeX packages. There don't seem to be many great examples showcasing this, as this functionality is mostly used by templates and rarely exposed to end users, but it would allow you to load additional JavaScript dependencies. This example is given here: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1654

Comment: html_document is also rendered when `extra_dependencies` is there but with `[autolanguage]` option there is an error.

Comment: @MichaelHarper, thank you for this. I initially had the same thought as you. But `?rmarkdown::html_document` shows that `html_document()` does take an `extra_dependencies` argument. So it does seem appropriate to use `extra_dependencies` and `output: html_document` together in the header of an R Markdown document. And as @J_F notes, you can do so without errors -- so long as you don't specify any options for the LaTeX packages that you load. (See my comment below on this point.) Do you think that we're missing something?

Comment: I have updated my answer to clarify. You can specify HTML dependencies but these have to be HTML compatible files like JavaScript. You are trying to make HTML use a LaTeX package, something which is not possible.

Comment: Thank you - I see on further inspection that this is the right answer. As @J_F noted, an R Markdown document with `output: html_document` and `extra_dependencies` that are LaTeX packages can be processed without any errors being thrown. But in such cases, the LaTeX packages won't actually be loaded or used by pandoc, and the HTML output may be a mess. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212009/697473) contains related information.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t knwo why this error occurs, but I have a workaround. Instead of using `extra_dependencies` you can use `header_includes`.

```yaml
---
title: "Test Processing of YAML Header in R Markdown Document"
output: 
  html_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{array}
  - \usepackage{numprint}["autolanguage"]
---
```

Comment: Thank you -- I knew about the workaround, but I really want to get `extra_dependencies` to work (and to know why it doesn't work).

Comment: ok, I think you known that the error just came from the `autolanguage` option.

Comment: Thank you, @J_F. You're right; if I eliminate the `autolanguage` option to the `numprint` package, everything works. But the problem isn't specific to that package or that option. It seems to arise whenever I try to create an HTML document while loading multiple LaTeX packages, some of which have options specified and others of which do not.